# Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Firemonkey ListView DynamicAppearance Multiselection

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, multi-select, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have selection problems with Firemonkey TListView when I set item appearance or edit item appearance to DynamicAppearance.

I am setting Listview.editMode := true; 
I have a glyphButton, it's style is checkbox.
I am trying to select lines, if appearance is DynamicAppearance it is not 
marking the glyphButton as checked but if appearance is different from DynamicAppearance it is working.

Anyone had and solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a issue in the Dynamic Appearance.

You can do this without entering in EditMode like showed here:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListViewCheckList_Sample

Or creating an specialized package for your ListView:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListViewMultiDetailAppearance_Sample

Maybe worth creating a entry in the Quality Portal and try to escalate.